# Can I use iMac G5 PowerPC for iOS app development?

Tags: ios, imac, development, g5

Can I use iMac G5 PowerPC for iOS app development? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you want to develop, if you want to use the official tools and SDK, then you are out of luck:

---

What are the requirements for developing with the iOS SDK and Xcode?

To develop with the iOS SDK and Xcode, you must have an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or later and you must be registered as an Apple Developer.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html)

Answer (score 1):

Officially, you can't develop iOS apps on a PowerPC machine. However, someone got Xcode working up to, but not including iPhone SDK 3.0. The details are available [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695839/843322)